# In a group $ABA = BA^2B, A^3 = 1$ and $B^{2n-1} = 1$. Prove $B = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, contest-math

Problem statement: Let $A$ and $B$ be two elements in a group such that $ABA = BA^2B, A^3 = 1$ and $B^{2n-1} = 1$ for some positive integer $n$. Prove $B = 1$.

I'm having trouble approaching this. A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$AB=(BA^2)^2$, $BA=(A^2B)^2$, hence $B^{-1}ABB=(B^{-1}BA^2B)^2=(A^2B)^2=BA$, i.e. $A$ commute with $B^2$, but $B$ has odd order this will lead to $A,B$ commute.

Comment: why does $B$ having an odd order imply that $A, B$ will commute?

Comment: Because $B=B^{2n}=(B^2)^n$

Comment: ohhh thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because $$A=(BA)(AB)(BA)^{-1},$$ which gives $$A^3=(BA)(AB)^3(BA)^{-1}$$ and from here $$(AB)^3=e.$$
Thus, $$(ABA)(BAB)=e$$ or $$BA^2BBAB=e$$ or $$A^2B^2A=B^{-2}$$ or $$A^{-1}B^2A=B^{-2},$$ which gives $$A^{-1}B^{2n}A=B^{-2n}$$ or
$$A^{-1}BA=B^{-1}$$ or $$BAB=A$$ and since $$ABABAB=e,$$ we obtain $$A^3B=e$$ or $$B=e.$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $G$ be the group, given that for $A\in G$ we have $A^3=1$ then the order of $G$ is 1 or 3. If $|G|=1$ then $G$ has a unique element, so $A=B=1$ and we finish. If $|G|=3$ then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and the elements of $G$ are $1, A, A^2$ so $B$ must be one of these three elements. If $B=A^2$ then $ABA=BBB \Rightarrow ABA=B^3 \Rightarrow AA^{2}A=1 \Rightarrow A=1$ which is impossible. Now if $B=A$ then since $ABA=BA^{2}B$ we have $A^3=A^4$ so $A=1$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $B=1$ \

Another case before that is that in case that $G$ has infinite order then $A^3=1$ implies $A=1$ so $ABA=BAAB$ implies $B=B^2$ so $B=1$

Comment: $A^3=e$ it's not an identity. See please better the given.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I didn´t understand what you tried to say.

Comment: A it's one  of elements from  G. You can say only that |G| is divided by 3. For example, |G|=21 is also valid.